# Converting MySQL Simple Query to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have Completed MySQL Simple Query,

```
SELECT 
  acc_trans.VoucherNumber,
  acc_trans.EntryDate,
  acc_trans.Debit,
  acc_trans.Credit,
  @Balance:= round(@Balance,2) + acc_trans.Debit - acc_trans.Credit AS  Balance
FROM acc_trans, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit Where AccountName='Cash Account'
ORDER BY  acc_trans.TransactionID ASC
```

output

```
VoucherNumber  EntryDate    Debit         Credit      Balance
-------------------------------------------------------------
1            2019-01-12      0.00       2500.00     -2500.00
2            2019-02-12      0.00      15000.00    -17500.00
3            2019-02-12      0.00       1500.00    -19000.00
1            2019-02-12   4800.00        0.00      -14200.00
```

This Query Working Good MySQL Database. I have Same Database with SQL Server.
How to Do this Query in SQL Server?

Comment: SQL is not database is that mean sql server?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin hmm   made my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from SQL Server 2008 you may use [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE acc_trans (
    TransactionID int,
    VoucherNumber int,
    EntryDate date,
    Debit numeric(20, 2),         
    Credit numeric(20, 2)
)
INSERT INTO acc_trans 
    (TransactionID, VoucherNumber, EntryDate, Debit, Credit)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2019-01-12',    0.00,  2500.00),
    (2, 2, '2019-02-12',    0.00, 15000.00),
    (3, 3, '2019-02-12',    0.00,  1500.00),
    (4, 1, '2019-02-12', 4800.00,     0.00)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
  acc_trans.VoucherNumber,
  acc_trans.EntryDate,
  acc_trans.Debit,
  acc_trans.Credit,
  [Balance] = SUM(acc_trans.Debit - acc_trans.Credit) OVER (ORDER BY  acc_trans.TransactionID ASC)
FROM acc_trans
WHERE AccountName = 'Cash Account'
```

Output:

```
VoucherNumber   EntryDate   Debit    Credit     Balance
1               2019-01-12  0.00     2500.00    -2500.00
2               2019-02-12  0.00     15000.00   -17500.00
3               2019-02-12  0.00     1500.00    -19000.00
1               2019-02-12  4800.00  0.00       -14200.00
```

Notes:

If you want to assign values to variables in SQL Server with SELECT statement, the remarks from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are important:

> SELECT @local_variable is typically used to return a single value into
>   the variable. However, when expression is the name of a column, it can
>   return multiple values. If the SELECT statement returns more than one
>   value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned.
>
> A SELECT statement that contains a variable assignment cannot be used
>   to also perform typical result set retrieval operations.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to work

```
declare @Balance int=0;

SELECT 
  acc_trans.VoucherNumber,
  acc_trans.EntryDate,
  acc_trans.Debit,
  acc_trans.Credit,
  @Balance = round(@Balance,2) + acc_trans.Debit - acc_trans.Credit AS  Balance
FROM acc_trans
Where AccountName='Cash Account'
ORDER BY  acc_trans.TransactionID ASC
```